# HTML / CSS Navbar vertical-align issue

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a child theme for WooCommerce's Storefront theme. My issue is with the navbar, where the navigation elements do not get centered horizontally. Please take a look at the code, as well as the image on the navbar. The navigation div has a background-color of red so it's easier to identify the issue.

[Navbar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXaSz.png)
| [JSFiddle with code](https://jsfiddle.net/u85ef73m/)

```css
.navbar {
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.logo p {
 color: #000;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 height: 70px;
 line-height: 70px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 width: 120px;
}

.logo {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 70px;
}

.navigation {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 background-color: red;
}

.navigation li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 line-height: 70px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 color: #333;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation li:hover {
 color: #D4B349;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">

 <div class="logo"><p> Lorem </p></div>

 <div class="navigation">
  <li> Home </li>
  <li> About </li>
  <li> Contact </li>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that your `logo` div is actually bigger than 70px, so your nav bar is being vertically aligned with it. If you remove 'line-height:70px;' for example, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the fact that your `inline-block` elements are not aligned.
So I've aligned them vertically.

Another thing, is that you don't need the `height:70px`, instead define `line-height: 70px`, on the parent, it will propagate to the children.

```css
.navbar {
 line-height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black; /* Change */
}

.logo p {
 color: #000;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 width: 120px;
}

.logo {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 background-color: red;
}

.navigation li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 line-height: 70px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 color: #333;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation li:hover {
 color: #D4B349;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">

 <div class="logo"><p> Lorem </p></div>

 <div class="navigation">
  <li> Home </li>
  <li> About </li>
  <li> Contact </li>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I asume that you want the logo far left and the social icons far right. To achieve this I would use:

```css
.logo {     
  float:left;
}

.icons {
  float: right;
}
```

you could also use position absolute.

Now you have two options:

1. aligning the navigation elements center. To do this you have to set the navigation to `text-align: center` and `display: block`:

   ```css
   .navigation {
     display: block;
     margin-left: 0px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: red;
   }
   ```
2. You could give the `.navbar` a `text-align: center`:

   ```css
   .navbar {
     height: 70px;
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   }
   ```